# Pointer increment with ++

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to brush up on my C and I have the following code it works when I use the i offset but not with hold++, I don't see why I thought they did same thing?
Here is the version I can't get to work:

```
char* reversestring2(char* s)
{
    int mysize = strlen(s);
    char* temp = s+mysize;
     //I do +1 for the terminator
    char* hold = (char*) malloc(mysize+1);

    while(temp > s)
    {
        *(hold) = *--temp;
        hold++;
    }
    *(hold++) = '\0';
    //printf("pre cpy %s", hold);
    strcpy(s,hold);
    //printf("%s", hold);
    return(s);
}
```

Thanks

```
char* reversestring(char* s)
{
    int mysize = strlen(s);
    char* temp = s+mysize;
    char* hold = (char*) malloc(mysize+1);
    int i=0;
    while(temp > s)
    {
        *(hold+i) = *--temp;
        //hold++;
        i++;
    }
    *(hold+i) = '\0';
    //printf("pre cpy %s", hold);
    strcpy(s,hold);
    //printf("%s", hold);
    return(s);
}

int main()
{
    //printf("%s\n", "you suck");
    char test[100] = "you suck";
    reversestring(test);
    printf("%s\n", test);
    //or
    char* hold = (char*) malloc(100);
    hold = reversestring(test);
    if(hold == NULL)
        printf("%s\n", "ERROR");
    printf("Second run: %s\n", hold);
}
```

Comment: Show us the version that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you incrementing BOTH hold and i?

Comment: If you use `malloc` or another such function that returns a pointer to memory that needs to be passed to a resource-freeing function such as `free`, you should either save the pointer to later free the memory it points to or simply avoid changing it. With `hold++`, you alter the pointer, and that means you cannot free it later. In short, "Hello, memory leak world!"

Comment: `hold = reversestring(test);` memory leak.

Comment: How is this a memory leak? I allocate memory for hold, then copy it back to s and return s which was passed in. Once reversestring is done so is the local malloc, I thought? I'm speaking of the hold in the reverse string function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `hold++`, the pointer `hold` advances to the end of the allocated array. Then you do this:

```
*(hold+i) = '\0';
```

which inserts a value into memory outside the bounds of the allocated space (e.g 200 steps from the beginning of an array of length 100), which causes undefined behavior. Then this:

```
strcpy(s,hold);
```

which copies who-knows-what from uncontrolled memory into the string.

Comment: When I allocated hold I did mysize + 1, the one for the terminator, I would think this would keep it from overflowing?

Comment: Thanks, I found my leaks using valgrind and reading about the heap. Also when I used hold I needed to put the pointer back to the first address.

Answer (score 0):

hold is a pointer variable which points to the beginning (first char element) of the block of memory that you allocate. hold++ will make it point to the next char in that block of memory.
hold = hold + 5 will make it point to the 6-th char in that block of memory and so on.

if you want to use hold++ instead, you need to delete i++, and replace *(hold+i) = *--temp; with *hold = *--temp; if you want so.

*hold is equivalent to *(hold + 0), I think you get the idea

Comment: When I try hold++ (not using the i to index it) it doesn't work.

Comment: That's right, it is not supposed to work if you do that, because right after the while loop finishes, you have *(hold+i) = '\0'; which will not have the desired results if you increment the hold pointer position using hold++ inside the loop.

Comment: Even if I allocate one more for the terminator? I would think I have to terminate hold to make it a string?

Comment: Thanks I got using valgrind and all comments.